# yii2 show data from related table

Tags: filter, datatable, yii2, filtering

I have two tables:

- **options**: with fiels "*id*(serial), *name*(varchar), *type*(int)".
- **options_activity**: same fields as in options table: ***id*, *name*, *type*** and: ***activity_id*(serial), *admin*(int), *date*(timestamp), *action*(int)**.

When I create an option, I save it in both the options table and in the options_activity. The options_activity table is a register; every time an admin creates/edit an option, the values of the option are registered in options table and copied ($model->attributes) in the options_activity and add the date, admin id and action field (1=created, 2=edited). That works ok.

So what I'm trying to do is, in the view of the option, show the view of the option and then, show a table below with all its activities (if there's an activity). How could I do this?

*Example (view):*

|Option: 1 | 'this is my option' | Type: 1

*Activities table (option 1):*

|-------------------------------------------------------------|

|Date: 2020-01-01 | Admin: 1 | Created | 'This is my option   |

|Date: 2020-01-03 | Admin: 1 | Edited | 'This is an option    |

|Date: 2020-02-10 | Admin: 2 | Edited | 'This is option       |

|-------------------------------------------------------------|

**I'm able to show every activity, but only want to show the activities of that particular option. I can't filter by it's ID.**

This is my **OptionsController**, the actionView($id):

```
public function actionView($id)
{
  $searchModel_act = new OptionsActivitySearch();
  $dataProvider_act = $searchModel_act->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
  $model_activity_op = new OptionsActivity();

  return $this->render('view', [
        'searchModel_act' => $searchModel_act,
        'dataProvider_act' => $dataProvider_act,
        'model_activity_op' => $model_activity_op,
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}
```

(also tryed other options trying to pass the id like 
$dataProvider_act = OpcionesActivity::find()->where(['id' => $id])->orderBy(['fecha' => SORT_ASC])->all();. Or ['id' => $model->id] but doesn't work.

My **view**:

```
<?=GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider_act,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel_act,
    'columns' => [
      ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        'opcion',
        'type',
        'date',
        'admin',
        'action',
    ],
]) 
?>
```

In my **model** I also tried this, to access to the activity but is not working:

```
public function getActivity()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OptionsActivity::class, ['id' => 'id']);
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: activity.columnName or $model->activity->columnName

Comment: I tryed this but doesn't work: $model = new Options();
$dataProvider_act = OptionsActivity::find()->where(['id' => $model->activity->id])->orderBy(['date' => SORT_DESC])->all(); 
I get this error: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: in GridView you can use 'activity.columnName' like an attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was much more simpler than I thought.

**In the controller:**

```
public function actionView($id)
{

  $searchModel = new OptionsActivitySearch();
  $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $id);

  //---------------------------
  return $this->render('view', [
      'model' => $this->findModel($id),
      'searchModel' => $searchModel,
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  ]);
}
```

**In the OptionsActivitySearch:**

```
    public function search($params, $id)
    {
        $query = OptionsActivity::find()->where(['id' => $id])->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC]);

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

//......
}
```

**In the view:**

...

(the gridView part):

```
    <?=         
        GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
//...
        ])
        ?>
```